# Counting letters inside paragraph

Tags: numbering, counters, enumitem

I am trying to make a new command `\part` which is defined such that each time I type
`\part` the output equals

```
\paragraph*(letter)
```

where **letter** is **bold**. So, with typing the letter manualy in, the working command is

```
 \newcommand{\del}[1]{\paragraph*{#1}}
```

Now. I must not have this inside a paragraph, I just want the output, identical to the output given with the command above. Just not having to type in the letter each time.

I am in no direct need to have very long number lists. So a-z should be fine. I also looked into counters and such, but could not produce anything close to working.

Also I was looking into the `enumitem` package. But this does not give me things in **bold**, nor the correct spacing. Also there is often quite some space, between each time I need a letter. For an example.

```
    \part Some text, questions

ipsulum, ipsulum
ipsulum, ipsulum
ipsulum, ipsulum
ipsulum, ipsulum

     part some text questions
```

So anyone got any solutions? =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\newcounter{subpart}[section]
\renewcommand{\thesubpart}{\alph{subpart}}
\newcommand{\subpart}{\stepcounter{subpart}\paragraph*{\thesubpart}}
```

Then

```
\subpart Some text, questions

ipsulum, ipsulum
ipsulum, ipsulum
ipsulum, ipsulum
ipsulum, ipsulum

\subpart some text questions
```

will give what you want.

As it is, the counter will reset at each section. If this is not wanted, delete `[section]` from the `\newcounter` line.

It's a bad idea to redefine `\part`.

Comment: Excellent. I just used \part here because it is in english. In my latex document I use . \del =)

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar: If you're interested in referring to these `\subpart`s by means of a `\label` - as in, `\subpart\label{mylab} Some text` ... `\ref{mylab}` - you need to use `\refstepcounter{subpart}` instead of `\stepcounter{subpart}` in the `\subpart` macro.